# No start when cold

Tags: starting, stall

I have a 2020 Baodiao 50cc scooter that really has a hard time starting when cold.

The engine turns over good but will not start. I have replaced the spark plug, coil, and engine control module.

I have also put a new battery in it and a new starter, starter drive and just had to replace the drive belt because the old one broke.

When I am riding it, it seems to be loosing power because it slows way down going up hill.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: How steep is the hill? Only the more powerful vehicles have enough power to hold their pace on a steep hill. If the spark plug colour is brown (below comment) it is healthy. For starting problems have you applied the choke? Or is it an automatic choke which is faulty?

Comment: Re "The engine turns over good". If that was the case before replacing the starter motor and the battery, go to a better workshop.

Answer (score 0):

The carburettor most likely needs cleaning/rebuilding, or adjusting.

The fact that it struggles on hills would make me think that the mixture isn’t correct.

Have you checked the colour of the deposits on the spark plug, which can indicated if it is running lean or rich?

Have you checked the fuel supply to the carburettor?

Have you replaced the air filter recently?  If that is completely blocked up, then maybe you are not getting sufficient air?

Comment: The spark plug is sort of brown looking, I checked the air filter and it is clean and I don't see any adjustments on the carburetor.